How soon after starting an LLC must start filing taxes?
I started an LLC, but haven't had any sales or profits yet, and won't for a year or so, after the business is ready. I'm the only employee and anyone I hire for work is through on-line services hiring freelancers. How soon do I need to start filing taxes with the IRS?

Why do you think you need to file taxes with the IRS at all? Have you elected to have your LLC be treated as a corporation?

I'm not sure if I need to pay taxes maybe related to income taxes for paying freelancers? I used a Web site called Reedsy to hire them.

In the US LLCs by default are disregarded entities for tax purposes and have no bearing on your Federal tax return (some States require LLCs to file tax returns though, e.g.: California). It may be wise to learn a bit about individual tax returns in the US and how business is handled in that context. See the IRS Publication 17 and the IRS Publication 334

@littleadv+ by default single-member LLC is disregarded and does not file its own return(s) but it definitely does affect (i.e. is included in) the owner's return. Simlarly multi-member is treated as 'passthrough' partnership which files 1065 with K-1 but does not pay tax, instead each partner reports their share of income and expense and pays tax on the net.

If you have startup costs you can claim them (even as a net loss) up to a limit for the first year or maybe two, as long as you report a profit (and pay tax) 3 out of 5 years. If you pay a contractor more than $600 per year you must file and 'furnish' (to the payee) 1099-NEC which is officially an information return not a tax return; IRS has a new website 'IRIS' to make this easier than it used to be, see https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/reporting-payments-to-independent-contractors .

while all @dave_thompson_085's proposals are true, none has anything to do with the timing of setting up the LLC (or the LLC itself). The costs of setting up the LLC are included in the "startup costs", but startup costs have to be amortized (see the IRS)


How soon do I need to start filing taxes with the IRS?

The taxes for the LLC are filed indirectly with the tax returns of the owner(s) either as a schedule C or as a K1 form. So you need to run your year end balance on the LLC, divvy up the profit or losses between the owner(s) who then include this in their personal tax returns.  All of that is due before April 15.

but haven't had any sales or profits yet

Doesn't matter. In fact any cost associated with starting or operating LLC (registration and/or state fees, business supplies, etc) can be claimed as a expenses so you can use the resulting loss to offset income from other sources.

Assuming it is a single-member LLC, you can deduct your business expenses (including freelancers' compensation) on your personal return, Schedule C.
